# Raspberrypi npm Package installation failure

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi3, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have the RPI Zero W, I'm trying to install npm in RPI using the following command
 `sudo apt-get install npm`
 But unfortunately it failed to fetch the package, i couldn't understand the Error log(I believe that the server is down, kindly correct me if i'm wrong), Have anyone solved this installation error before, i have attached the log below:

```
    ~/Desktop/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/companionService $ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  coinor-libipopt1 libboost-filesystem1.55.0 libboost-program-options1.55.0 libboost-regex1.55.0 libffi5 libgmime-2.6-0 libmumps-seq-4.10.0 liboauth0 libraw10
  wolframscript
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gyp libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libv8-3.14-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-block-stream node-combined-stream
  node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs
  node-gyp node-inherits node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid
  node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver
  node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-which nodejs-dev
Suggested packages:
  node-hawk node-aws-sign node-oauth-sign node-http-signature
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gyp libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libv8-3.14-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-block-stream node-combined-stream
  node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs
  node-gyp node-inherits node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid
  node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver
  node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-which nodejs-dev npm
0 upgraded, 52 newly installed, 0 to remove and 80 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,428 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,840 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  gyp libjs-node-uuid libv8-3.14-dev node-async node-node-uuid node-underscore libc-ares-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-inherits
  node-block-stream node-delayed-stream node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-forever-agent node-mime node-form-data node-rimraf node-mkdirp node-graceful-fs
  node-fstream node-lru-cache node-sigmund node-minimatch node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-once node-glob nodejs-dev node-nopt node-npmlog
  node-osenv node-tunnel-agent node-json-stringify-safe node-qs node-request node-semver node-tar node-which node-gyp node-ini node-lockfile node-mute-stream
  node-normalize-package-data node-read node-read-package-json node-retry node-sha node-slide npm
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main gyp all 0.1~svn1729-3
  Could not connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:80 (202.116.65.189), connection timed out
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main libjs-node-uuid all 1.4.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main libv8-3.14-dev armhf 3.14.5.8-8.1+rpi1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-async all 0.8.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-node-uuid all 1.4.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-underscore all 1.7.0~dfsg-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main libc-ares-dev armhf 1.10.0-2+deb8u1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-abbrev all 1.0.5-2
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-ansi all 0.3.0-2
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-ansi-color-table all 1.0.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-archy all 0.0.2-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-inherits all 2.0.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-block-stream all 0.0.7-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-delayed-stream all 0.0.5-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-combined-stream all 0.0.5-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-cookie-jar all 0.3.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-forever-agent all 0.5.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-mime all 1.2.11-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-form-data all 0.1.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-rimraf all 2.2.8-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-mkdirp all 0.5.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-graceful-fs all 3.0.2-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-fstream all 0.1.24-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-lru-cache all 2.3.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-sigmund all 1.0.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-minimatch all 1.0.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-fstream-ignore all 0.0.6-2
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-github-url-from-git all 1.1.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-once all 1.1.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-glob all 4.0.5-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main nodejs-dev armhf 0.10.29~dfsg-2
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-nopt all 3.0.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-npmlog all 0.0.4-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-osenv all 0.1.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-tunnel-agent all 0.3.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-json-stringify-safe all 5.0.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-qs all 2.2.4-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-request all 2.26.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-semver all 2.1.0-2
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-tar all 0.1.18-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-which all 1.0.5-2
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-gyp all 0.12.2+ds-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-ini all 1.1.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-lockfile all 0.4.1-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-mute-stream all 0.0.4-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-normalize-package-data all 0.2.2-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-read all 1.0.5-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-read-package-json all 1.2.4-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-retry all 0.6.0-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-sha all 1.2.3-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main node-slide all 1.1.4-1
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
Err http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie/main npm all 1.4.21+ds-2
  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/g/gyp/gyp_0.1~svn1729-3_all.deb  Could not connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:80 (202.116.65.189), connection timed out

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-uuid/libjs-node-uuid_1.4.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libv/libv8-3.14/libv8-3.14-dev_3.14.5.8-8.1+rpi1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-async/node-async_0.8.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-uuid/node-node-uuid_1.4.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/u/underscore/node-underscore_1.7.0~dfsg-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/c/c-ares/libc-ares-dev_1.10.0-2+deb8u1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-abbrev/node-abbrev_1.0.5-2_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-ansi/node-ansi_0.3.0-2_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-ansi-color-table/node-ansi-color-table_1.0.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-archy/node-archy_0.0.2-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-inherits/node-inherits_2.0.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-block-stream/node-block-stream_0.0.7-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-delayed-stream/node-delayed-stream_0.0.5-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-combined-stream/node-combined-stream_0.0.5-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-cookie-jar/node-cookie-jar_0.3.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-forever-agent/node-forever-agent_0.5.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-mime/node-mime_1.2.11-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-form-data/node-form-data_0.1.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-rimraf/node-rimraf_2.2.8-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-mkdirp/node-mkdirp_0.5.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-graceful-fs/node-graceful-fs_3.0.2-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-fstream/node-fstream_0.1.24-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-lru-cache/node-lru-cache_2.3.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-sigmund/node-sigmund_1.0.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-minimatch/node-minimatch_1.0.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-fstream-ignore/node-fstream-ignore_0.0.6-2_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-github-url-from-git/node-github-url-from-git_1.1.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-once/node-once_1.1.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-glob/node-glob_4.0.5-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs-dev_0.10.29~dfsg-2_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-nopt/node-nopt_3.0.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-npmlog/node-npmlog_0.0.4-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-osenv/node-osenv_0.1.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-tunnel-agent/node-tunnel-agent_0.3.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-json-stringify-safe/node-json-stringify-safe_5.0.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-qs/node-qs_2.2.4-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-request/node-request_2.26.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-semver/node-semver_2.1.0-2_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-tar/node-tar_0.1.18-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-which/node-which_1.0.5-2_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-gyp/node-gyp_0.12.2+ds-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-ini/node-ini_1.1.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-lockfile/node-lockfile_0.4.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-mute-stream/node-mute-stream_0.0.4-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-normalize-package-data/node-normalize-package-data_0.2.2-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-read/node-read_1.0.5-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-read-package-json/node-read-package-json_1.2.4-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-retry/node-retry_0.6.0-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-sha/node-sha_1.2.3-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/node-slide/node-slide_1.1.4-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.sysu.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/npm/npm_1.4.21+ds-2_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.sysu.edu.cn:http:

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Is there any other way to install this package?
Looking forward to hear your suggestions.
-Suresh

Comment: can you try sudo apt-get install nodejs npm

Answer (score 1):

As npm should be compiled with node, you can try this:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.1/node-v6.11.1.tar.gz

sudo tar -xvzf node-v6.11.1.tar.gz

cd node-v6.11.1

sudo make install
```